# Uncaught Reference Error: mapboxgl is undefined

Tags: undefined, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am dynamically loading Mapbox-GL JS in this way:

```
        var script = domConstruct.create("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.charset = "utf-8";
        script.onload = instantiateMap();
        script.src = "https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.js";
        script.async = false;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Then at some point, I am accessing it as follows in the 'instantiateMap' function:

```
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibW11a2ltIiwiYSI6ImNqNnduNHB2bDE3MHAycXRiOHR3aG0wMTYifQ.ConO2Bqm3yxPukZk6L9cjA';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
         container: mapParent,
         style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'
        });
```

As soon as my control reaches the line (mapboxgl.accessToken...) it gives me the following error on Chrome Console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined
    at Object._instantiateMap (VM2337 Sample.js:282)
_instantiateMap @ VM2337 Sample.js:282
```

This particular code snippet works fine in the following situations:
- Including Mapbox-GL.js dynamically also works fine in an independent HTML file.
- Including the library statically in the HTML files.

I know that the library loads fine because I see it in the left panel under Sources, but I have no idea as to why while accessing mapboxgl object, this error comes up.

Also I have tried including other libraries (jQuery, mapbox.js) in a similar fashion and they work fine.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think the "Then at some point" is your problem. You need to make sure the script is run before you do anything with it.

Comment: UPDATE: The cause was the Dojo loader being loaded before I am trying to load the script and since this loader is now responsible for loading the scripts moving forward, it recognizes that Mapbox-GL is not an AMD module and hence it does not load it correctly. Also I am using the Dojo 'require' to load the scripts dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the source code I can't test or fix the error.

My guess would be that the script is not loaded before the instantiation either because of the size of the script or the order of the code.

I would personally use a call back function for this to ensure instantiation only happens when the file has been fully downloaded (not tested)

```
    JavaScript.load("https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.js", function() {
       mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibW11a2ltIiwiYSI6ImNqNnduNHB2bDE3MHAycXRiOHR3aG0wMTYifQ.ConO2Bqm3yxPukZk6L9cjA';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
         container: mapParent,
         style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'
        }); 
    });

    var JavaScript = {
      load: function(src, callback) {
        var script = document.createElement('script'),
            loaded;
        script.setAttribute('src', src);
        if (callback) {
          script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function() {
            if (!loaded) {
              callback();
            }
            loaded = true;
          };
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely, js script has run before loading dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue in express:
In the response that is getting sent back, add the following

```
res.status(200).set(
      'Content-Security-Policy',
      'connect-src https://*.tiles.mapbox.com https://api.mapbox.com https://events.mapbox.com'
    ).render('whatever', {} );
```